# L-Value, Pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, lvalue, pointer-arithmetic

I am looking for an explanation of how lines L1 and L2 in the code snippet below differ w.r.t `l-values`, i.e, Why am I getting the: `C2105 error` in L1, but not in L2?

```
*s = 'a';
printf("%c\n", *s );
//printf("%c\n", ++(*s)++ ); //L1 //error C2105: '++' needs l-value
printf("%c\n", (++(*s))++);  //L2
printf("%c\n", (*s) );
```

Note: I got the above result when the code was compiled as a .cpp file. Now, on compilation as .c file, I get the same error C2105 on both lines L1 and L2. Why does L2 compile in C++, and not in C is another mystery :(.

If its of any help, I'm using Visual C++ Express Edition.

Comment: Read [Why `++i++` gives “L-value required error” in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850851/why-i-gives-l-value-required-error-in-c)

Comment: `(++(*s))++)` compiles? Which compiler you are using? version?

Comment: [Both are l-value errors](http://codepad.org/bbfJmMJm) in C

Comment: L2 provides a valid l-value, L1 does not. It would probably help you to understand that post-increment doesn't actually increment post-*expression* (most think it does, including, unfortunately, all-too-many profs in academia). It saves the current value to a temporary, then increments the l-value, then returns a r-value from the temporary. Since pre-increment requires an l-value, you're getting a correct and accurate error condition.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan This is where C and C++ differ.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Yes you are right. On GCC 4.7.1, it is giving error for both.

Comment: @jrok I concur, so what to do when the OP has *both* languages in the tag-list =P ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I feel Jrok has a point in [C++ only fist line give error](http://ideone.com/3pWKXE) Why?

Comment: Note: the question I linked itself duplicated with **wrong** question. I have already flag that!

Comment: Note: `(++(*s))++)` is equivalent to `++*s++` So using prefix increment value of `*s` will be incremented and using postfix `++` value of `s` incremented to point to next location Read: [Find the fault or error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818866/find-the-fault-or-error). Whereas in expression `++(*s)++` post first and prefix applied to `*s` and this is a compilation time error dues to reason in linked answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler see `++(*s)++` as `++((*s)++)`, as post-increment has higher precedence than pre-increment. After post-incrementation, `(*s)++` becomes an r-value and it can't be further pre-incremented (here).
And yes it is not a case of UB (at least in C).
And also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850934/2455888).

For L2 in **C++** not giving error because
**C++11: 5.3.2 Increment and decrement** says:

> The **operand of prefix ++** is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated). The
>   operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a completely-defined object type. **The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue**, and it is a bit-field if the operand is a bit-field. If x is not of type bool, the expression ++x is equivalent to x+=1.

**C++11:5.2.6 Increment and decrement** says:

> The **value of a postfix ++ expression** is the value of its operand. [ Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value —end note ] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a complete object type. The value of the operand object is modified by adding 1 to it, unless the object is of type bool, in which case it is set to true. The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before the modification of the operand object. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix
>   ++ is a single evaluation. [ Note: Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated with any single postfix ++ operator. —end note ] **The result is a
>   prvalue**. The type of the result is the cv-unqualified version of the type of the operand.

and also on [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx) it is stated that:

> The operands to **postfix** increment and postfix decrement operators must be modifiable (not const) l-values of arithmetic or pointer type. The type of the result is the same as that of the postfix-expression, but **it is no longer an l-value**.

Comment: Pre and post-increment operators have same precedence, but compiler sees ++(*s)++ as ++((*s)++) because the associativity is right-to-left.

Comment: This is not UB but it violates a constraint.

Comment: @VivereJay postfix increment operator has higher precedence than prefix increment operator. The right-associativity of postfix and unary operators is just another way to say this.

Comment: @haccks don't need to check, the operand of the prefix increment operator has to be a modifiable lvalue in C and the result of the postfix operator is not a lvalue.

Comment: @VivereJay look at the standard. The operators are presented in order of precedence (high to low), and §6.5.2 Postfix operators comes before §6.5.3 Unary operators. -- postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators --

Comment: @ouah A monstrously valid point. The fact that an error condition is being raised lends validity to that fact that it *is* defined at compile-time (as invalid =).

Comment: I changed my mind, `(++(*s))++;` is UB (at least in C++).

Answer (score 1):

**For completeness and quotes from C++ documentation:**

Looking at L2, the prefix-increment/decrement returns an l-value. Hence, no error when performing the post-increment. From the C++ documentation for prefix-increment/decrement:

> The result is an l-value of the same type as the operand.

Looking at L1, it becomes:

```
++( ( *s )++ )
```

... after operand precedence. The post-increment operator by definition evaluates the expression (returning an r-value) and then mutates it. From C++ documentation for post-increment/decrement:

> The type of the result is the same as that of the postfix-expression, but it is no longer an l-value.

... and you cannot prefix-increment/decrement an r-value, hence error.

**References:**

- [Postfix Operand Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx).
- [Prefix Operand Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy3d35h8.aspx).

Comment: *"The result is an l-value of the same type as the operand"* Citation needed.

Comment: @jrok, included references.

Comment: That's a C++ reference, and not an authoritative one, at that.

Comment: @jrok, and the post is tagged as `C++`... otherwise I would not use `C++` references.

Comment: Your answer says: *"From the **C** documentation for prefix-increment/decrement:The result is an l-value of the same type as the operand."* Which is incorrect. In C the result is not an lvalue.

Comment: @jrok, fixed to clarify C++ -- typo.

Comment: In case anyone is interested on the C++ side, **C++11 § 5.3.2,p1** "The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a completely-defined object type. The result is the updated operand; *it is an lvalue*, and it is a bit-field if the operand is a bit-field. If x is not of type bool, the expression ++x is equivalent to x+=1..."