# Char pointer in C works unexpectedly

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
    char *p = "ayqm";
    char c;
    c = ++*p++;
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

I thought it should print 'c' but it prints 'b'. Please explain.

Comment: @usr that is for C++, not C. Also, this is not undefined behavior like in that question (as p itself is not reused).

Comment: It works unexpectedly because it's gibberish.  Even if someone can show that it's "legal", it's nothing you should actually code.

Comment: I protest: to close this as a duplicate of [Undefined Behaviour and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) is an outrageous injustice; the expression is has no undefined behaviour related to modifying the same value twice in a single expression, which is what the other question is about.  However, the code in [Find the fault or error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818866/find-the-fault-or-error) does use `++*p++` and tries to modify a literal string — that is a good duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression can be broken down as follows, which can clarify what happens.

```
c = ++*p++;

steps:

1) (*p)         // (*p) == 'a'
2) ++(*p)       // (*p) == 'b'
3) c = (*p)     // c == 'b'
4) p++          // p -> 'y'
```

EDIT : edited to clarify modification of (*p) per comments

Comment: Is this even defined behavior? The sequence of actions seems undefined.

Comment: I believe that, in this case, the operator precedence, and binding rules apply clearly enough for it not to be undefined behavior.

Comment: `c = ++*p++` is completely defined behaviour as long as `p` points to modifiable data.  In the question, it points to a string literal which may not be modified; however, avoiding that problem is simple (`char a[] = "ayqm"; char *p = a;`) and the expression is then 100% legitimate — albeit something that should not be used in reviewed codein the ordinary course of business.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The value of `*p++` ought to be incremented as well. `p` now correctly points at `'y'` but the value of `'a'` should be a `'b'`, too. But your steps do not reflect this.

Comment: @usr I think Ziffusion means *`can be`* broken down. Yes it is undefined as it also modify const string literal

Comment: @bitmask: you're correct that the string is modified to become `"byqm"` (as well as `c` containing `'b'`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is  the expression: `++*p++;` same as `++p[i++]` not undefined ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Under what circumstances do you think `++p[i++]` is undefined behaviour?  Assuming `p` and `i` are not aliassed in some contorted way, and `i` is appropriately initialized to an index in the range of the array of objects pointed to by `p`, the expression `++p[i++]` is perfectly well-formed and completely defined behaviour.  If `i` is too large (or too small), or `p` points to readonly data, then you have problems; otherwise, it is fine.  The proscribed behaviour is modifying a single value twice between sequence points, as in `a[i++] = ++i;`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), it makes the postfix `++` operator increase the *pointer* and not the dereferenced value.

So your expression returns the first `'a'` which is increased by the prefix increase to `'b'`, but due to the above mentioned operator precedence the postfix increase is actually for the pointer.

Comment: damn beat me to it haha, i literally was just about to post this same thing

Answer (score 0):

Here postfix has the highest precedence but it will the effect the value only after the statement. ++ and * have same precedence, and they have right associativity. There for it will work like this:

*p -> evaluates to a

then ++'a' which evaluates to 'b'