# Order of execution of operator

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused of operator precedence table give in http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

I mean right-to-left and left-to-right.

I want to know in what order the operator will we applied on this  code.

```
int main()
{
   int i[] = {3, 5}; 
   int *p = i; 
   int j = --*p++; 

   printf("j = %d\n\n", j);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Is it like  `--(*(p++))`? or `(--(*p))++` ? Its very confusing. is there any standard rule to resolve this problem.

Comment: The question you should be asking is why you are even contemplating writing code like this. Do you like pain?

Comment: I agree with David, once you get a basic understanding, if you have to read documentation/write a test/ask to SO, probably your expression is your complex that either it is very likely to not behave as expected or your coworkers will have to read documentation/write a test/ask to SO to understand it (or both of the options). Lines of code are free, just make your expression longer.

Comment: **Note**: Expression `(--(*p))++` (is equivalents to `--(*p)++`)  will be a **compilation time error**: `Not an lvalue`. To understand it Read: [Why `++i++` gives “L-value required error” in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850851/why-i-gives-l-value-required-error-in-c/17850934#17850934)

Answer (score 4):

The expression:

```
j = --*p++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
j = --*p;  // first decrements value pointed by p, then assign value pointer by p to j
p++;       // increment p to point to next location
```

The parenthesis version of your expression should be : `--(*(p++));` Read @[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551127/1673391).

I would also suggest you to read @[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) answer: [Incrementing Pointers, Exact Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935062/1673391) to understand `++` and `*` operator expression that how a compiler can perform it at low level.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `--` will always be parsed by the compiler as the decrement operator.

Comment: @DerFlatulator Yes `--` parsed as decrements operator. `---`  will be pareses as `-- -`

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused by the operator precedence table give in http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm. What does right-to-left and left-to-right mean in this table?

Precedence and associativity determine how the parentheses are logically inserted into an underparenthesized expression. If you have

```
x + y * z
```

then `*` is higher precedence, so it wins, and this is:

```
x + (y * z)
```

not

```
(x + y) * z
```

If you have two operators that have the same precedence then which one wins depends on the associativity.  `+` and `-` are the same precedence and have left-to-right associativity, so

```
x + y - z
```

is

```
(x + y) - z
```

And not

```
x + (y - z)
```

Operators with right-to-left associativity put the parentheses on the rightmost expression first.

> I want to know in what order the operator will we applied on this code. `--*p++`

Well, follow the chart. We have `*`, prefix decrement and postfix increment.  Consult the precedence table first. Postfix increment is higher precedence than the other two, so automatically this is `--*(p++)`.  And now we do not need to consult the table to work out the rest; clearly the only possible parenthesization is `--(*(p++))`.

Comment: *`Precedence and associativity determine how the parentheses are logically inserted into an underparenthesized expression`* opposite is  also true that "parentheses are used to overwrite precedence of operator in an expression". e.g. in `(x + y) * z`, `+` that is low in precedence executes before then `*`.

Answer (score 1):

`++` and `--` Prefix increment/decrement right-to-left 
and later on you found `*`

```
j = --*p++;
```

Above statement according to precedence `--` will perform first. So in expression `--` is  pre-decrement on `*p` and then `++` is post increment, will increment pointer `p`.

```
j= --*p; //and immediately do *p++ == p++ , because here ++ got priority. and this is post decrement this wont assign to j.this as same as incrementing p value in next statement. 
p++;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tricks on prefix increment and postfix increment.
As a programmer, you do not need to spend too much time on those tricks, just use brackets in your code to show the computing order.